# Cascading selects with default values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have a 3 tier cascading select list that I have implemented using knockout.js / jQuery / json.

There may be instances where a select box only has 1 choice within it - in which case I'd like to not force the user to have to manually select it and instead default it to the single value, and cascade down to the next box automatically. Can this be done?

My select lists (the first is currently slightly different because it's generated by MVC Razor view with values supplied direct from view model):

```html
<!--Variants-->
<select class="dim" data-bind="value: selectedDim1" id="Dim1" name="Dim1" onchange="FetchDim2();"><option selected="selected" value="">Select Colour</option>
<option value="Black">Colour:Black</option>
<option value="NAVYBLUE">Colour:Navy Blue</option>
</select>
<select id="Dim2" data-bind="value: selectedDim2, options: ddlDim2, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', optionsCaption: 'Select Waist Size'" class="dim"></select>
<select id="Dim3" data-bind="value: selectedDim3, options: ddlDim3, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', optionsCaption: 'Select Leg Length'" class="dim"></select>
```

My knockout code:

```js
function DDLViewModel() {
        this.ddlDim1 = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.ddlDim2 = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.ddlDim3 = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.selectedDim1 = ko.observable();
        this.selectedDim1.subscribe(FetchDim2, this);
        this.selectedDim2 = ko.observable();
        this.selectedDim2.subscribe(FetchDim3, this);
        this.selectedDim3 = ko.observable();
        this.selectedDim3.subscribe(FetchVariant, this);
    }

    var objVM = new DDLViewModel();
    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(objVM);

    function FetchDim2() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/product/getdims/', // we are calling json method
            dataType: 'json',
            // here we get value of selected dim.
            data: { id: 20408,
                level: 2,
                head: 'Waist Size',
                code: $("#Dim1").val()
            },
            success: function (dims) {
                // dims contains the JSON formatted list of dims passed from the controller
                objVM.ddlDim2(dims);
                objVM.ddlDim3.removeAll();
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve dims.' + ex);
            }
        });
    }

    function FetchDim3() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/product/getdims/', // we are calling json method
            dataType: 'json',
            // here we get value of selected dim.
            data: { id: 20408,
                level: 3,
                head: 'Leg Length',
                code: $("#Dim2").val()
            },
            success: function (dims) {
                // dims contains the JSON formatted list of dims passed from the controller
                objVM.ddlDim3(dims);
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve dims.' + ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

I guess I (a) need to specify a default value if there is only on choice and (b) force the call of the code that populates the next level down? Not sure how to do either without breaking it all though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes! Don't mix jQuery and Knockout like that. Don't let jQuery do DOM manipulation (e.g. `val(...)`) but instead get the selected value from your view model.

This will also greatly simplify your view, as things like those `id` attributes become irrelevant.

Furthermore, I recommend making the `Fetch...` methods a dependency for your view model. In my example below I just inline those functions inside the view model constructor function, but you could also wrap them in a service and have that service as a dependency (you'd still have to provide input and success handlers to that service of course).

Another thing, quite needed / useful if you follow the above advice: use the `var self = this` idiom, instead of reiterating `this` everywhere / providing the `this` argument everywhere.

With all those things changed, it becomes trivial to fix your original question. Triggering cascaded updates can be done inside the success functions. Before I show the full snippet, here's the nitty gritty for your actual question:

```
success: function(dims) {
  self.ddlDim3(dims);
  if (dims.length === 1) {
    self.selectedDim3(dims[0].Value);
  }
}
```

Simply put, this selects the first option if there is only one, and lets Knockout handle updating the DOM (and cascading, if needed).

Here's a full demo based off your original code:

```js
// Fake the Ajax requests:
var $ = {
  ajax: function(options) {
    if (options.data.level === 2 && options.data.code === "Black") {
      options.success([{
        Text: "Waist size S",
        Value: "S"
      }, {
        Text: "Waist size M",
        Value: "M"
      }, {
        Text: "Waist size L",
        Value: "L"
      }]);
    }

    if (options.data.level === 2 && options.data.code === "NAVYBLUE") {
      options.success([{
        Text: "Waist size M",
        Value: "M"
      }]);
    }

    // Not faking lvl 3 as extensively, but the same would hold as above.
    if (options.data.level === 3) {
      options.success([{
        Text: "Legs 40",
        Value: "40"
      }]);
    }
  }
};

function DDLViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.ddlDim1 = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.ddlDim2 = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.ddlDim3 = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedDim1 = ko.observable();
  self.selectedDim1.subscribe(FetchDim2);
  self.selectedDim2 = ko.observable();
  self.selectedDim2.subscribe(FetchDim3);
  self.selectedDim3 = ko.observable();
  self.selectedDim3.subscribe(FetchVariant);

  function FetchDim2() {
    console.log(2);

    $.ajax({
      url: '/product/getdims/',
      data: {
        id: 20408,
        level: 2,
        head: 'Waist Size',
        code: self.selectedDim1()
      },
      success: function(dims) {
        self.ddlDim2(dims);
        self.ddlDim3.removeAll();
        if (dims.length === 1) {
          self.selectedDim2(dims[0].Value);
        } else {
          self.selectedDim2(null);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function FetchDim3() {
    if (!self.selectedDim2()) {
      self.ddlDim3.removeAll();
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        data: {
          id: 20408,
          level: 3,
          head: 'Leg Length',
          code: self.selectedDim2()
        },
        success: function(dims) {
          self.ddlDim3(dims);
          if (dims.length === 1) {
            self.selectedDim3(dims[0].Value);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function FetchVariant() {
    // Noop / not provided in question
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new DDLViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="value: selectedDim1">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Select Colour</option>
  <option value="Black">Colour:Black</option>
  <option value="NAVYBLUE">Colour:Navy Blue</option>
</select>

<select data-bind="value: selectedDim2, options: ddlDim2, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', optionsCaption: 'Select Waist Size'"></select>

<select data-bind="value: selectedDim3, options: ddlDim3, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', optionsCaption: 'Select Leg Length'"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks very much  - I ripped some of the code from a jQuery version I had working hence the mix and match - it's working it seems but I need to do the same with the first drop down - if there is only once choice, select it and populate drop down 2 - however that is populated by the MVC view model up front - should I swap that to work the same way as the other 2 drop downs? If so can I force it when the page loads? Would this also cascade down so that if 1, 2, & 3 only had one choice they would all be filled in?

Comment: Also I have created my FetchVariant() function but I cannot for the life of me get access to the resultant data - do I have to map the observableArray to another model to be able to use it throughout my page?

Comment: You ask really rather broad follow-up questions. I recommend asking a new Stack Overflow question for each seperate case, including reduced examples for each. In addition, you may need a friend or colleague to help think through the design. Also, if you haven't already, check out the KnockoutJS tutorials. (Mixing server-side prepopulated select boxes with client side MVVM through KnockoutJS can be an hairy subject...)